# "Put Response Body In Attribute" not working in invokeHTTP

Tags: apache-nifi

I have tried set the "Put Response Body In Attribute" of invokeHTTP to true, $.result, $(result), $.* but none of those worked. How to
make it work ? Thanks.

Comment: there should be just a name of attribute where to put response. so just put there `result` for example.

Comment: I just found out it did worked. I expect those field appears in flowfile but it's showed as attributes. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Name of attribute for “Put Response Body In Attribute” in invokeHTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57760560/name-of-attribute-for-put-response-body-in-attribute-in-invokehttp)

Comment: It's not same problem.